# VBA How to programmatically set objects name?

Tags: vba

In FactoryTalk View SE I’m trying to set an objects name in VBA based on another value.

This works:

```
Dim PumpSP As Object

Set PumpSP = ThisDisplay.PumpSetpoint1

PumpSP.Vaule = 10
```

This doesn’t work:

```
Dim PumpSP As Object

Set PumpSP = "ThisDisplay.PumpSetpoint" & "1"

PumpSP.Vaule = 10
```

How do I get it to take a concatenated string?

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance we can take a step back and explain what the broader goal is here?

Comment: try some thing like this `Set PumpSP.name = "ThisDisplay.PumpSetpoint" & "1"`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with FactoryTalk View, but you can't access a member of an object with a string like that. I suspect what you need to do is loop over whatever collection you would find `PumpSetpoint1` in to find it.

Comment: urdearboy - thanks for the format edit, I was trying to do that when you did it for me.

Comment: Adding ".Name" breaks it. :(

Comment: PumpSetpoint1 - I was hoping to not have to do a loop but it looks like that is what would be needed. There are a few hundred objects on the screen and it just seemed silly not to be able to ask for the one I want. Would you do loop or case or...? I know little of VBA.

Comment: You can try `Set PumpSP = CallByName(ThisDisplay, "PumpSetpoint1", vbGet)` if your environment supports `CallByName`

Comment: We have paid support with Rockwell but they will not help with any VBA questions. Ok fine but their VBA commands and class are not like 90% of the Excel or MS Office VBA you find online. Anyway I was able to find the correct class member. So this work for me: “Set PumpSP  = ThisDisplay.FindElement("PumpSetpoint" & “1”)” Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the hard part as we have paid support with Rockwell but they will not help with any VBA questions. Ok fine but there VBA commands and class are not like 90% of the Excel or MS Office VBA you find online. Anyway I was able to find the correct class member.

So this work for me:
`Set PumpSP  = ThisDisplay.FindElement("PumpSetpoint" & “1”)` Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do I get it to take a concatenated string?*

You don't, and you can't. `PumpSP` is an `Object`, not a `String`. The only thing you can ever `Set` it to, is an object reference.

This is very similar to, say, how you would access the controls on a `UserForm`:

```
Set box = Me.TextBox1
```

The reason you can get that object with a string, is because a form has a `Controls` collection that lets you provide a string, works out which control has that name, and returns the `Control` object for it:

```
Set box = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
```

So in your case to go from this:

```
Set PumpSP = ThisDisplay.PumpSetpoint1
```

I don't know what `ThisDisplay` is, but maybe it has a similar collection:

```
Set PumpSP = ThisDisplay.Controls("PimpSetpoint" & i)
```

If there's no collection that lets you retrieve items by name with a string literal, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Tanquen You need to look into your API (specifically `ThisDisplay` and see what's available there. Look for a collection property of some sort. Reference the type library, then hit F2 for the *Object Browser*. This is specific to the API you're using, not VBA. I can't help you any more than that, I don't know anything about `ThisDisplay` and your post doesn't include any hint whatsoever about what it might be.

Comment: All the objects are there in VBA but nothing popups for Controls. So I guess I have to loop through them all but I'm not having any luck with the syntax for it.  

`            For Each Item In ThisDisplay
                If Item.Name Like "PumpSetpoint1" Then
                    Item.Value = 10
                End If
            Next Item

Comment: Notice how I've mentioned several times that **I know nothing about the API you're using**, so it's entirely possible there's no `.Controls` member. This answer isn't telling you to do `.Controls` either - it's telling you to look for a collection property in your API. If `ThisDisplay.Item(i)` is valid, then maybe `ThisDisplay.Item("PimpSetpoint" & i)` is worth a shot?

Comment: Sorry, fist time posting and I can't even get the format in the comment to work. :(

Comment: Notice I’m trying and I was typing my last reply while you had posted yours. I know little of VBA. - In the Object Browser there is no "Controls" Member for the ThisDisplay class, no “Item” either if that matters. Not sure where ThisDisplay.Item(i) would be tested. Also, its PUMP not PIMP. :) It looks like a For each loop is the way to go but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Try right-clicking a blank area in the object browser, then select "show hidden members" - it's likely that the `Item` property is there, just hidden.